What type of fruit tree is this in NYC?
I love this tree! It is thriving in September on a roof deck in New York City. What species is it? The leaves are 4 inches long by 2 inches wide. It's 8 feet 4 inches tall.


I believe you love a kousa dogwood!  Worth noting that it is invasive in New York, although your tree looks well contained.

Leaf: Opposite, simple, oval to ovate with an entire margin, arcuate
venation, 2 1/2 to 4 inches long, 2 to 2 1/2 inches wide, shiny dark
green above, paler below with some tufts of golden-brown hair present
particularly at base of petiole.
Flower: Species is monoecious; white
to slightly yellow-white bracts surround a cluster of small
inconspicuous flowers; white bracts are very showy, 2 to 3 inches
across and often cover the entire plant in late spring (after
flowering dogwood).
Fruit: Very unusual, edible drupe, light red to
pink in color, round and 1 to 1 1/2 inches across; yellowish orange
inside and contains stony pits, borne on a 1 1/2 to 2 inch stalk,
ripen in late summer to early fall.
Twig: Slender, with initially some
purple or green but later turning light brown; leaf buds resemble a
cat claw, flower buds are considerably larger and heart-shaped.
Bark: Initially smooth and light brown, later exfoliating into small > patches forming a tan and brown camouflage pattern.
Form: Typically multiple
stems, wide branching reaching a height of 30 feet.
Looks like: flowering dogwood - Pacific dogwood

A lot of dogwoods have leaves like your tree there, but the fruit is very distinctive.  I couldn't make out much bark in the pictures, but I would not be surprised if it is still too young to show exfoliation.


Thanks for your detailed answer! I tasted the fruit, it's pleasant.

It looks almost like an aberration of a litchi but then litchis are not single stem fruit...they come in bunches. They also have the stone pit and a brown hard outer skin. They don't have what appears to be the bumps on the fruit...but they are very sensitive to cold so probably would not be doing so well in NYC.

Hi Kevin, are you able to supply a reference?  I don't think it looks like a litchi at all.
